Glossaries Acronyms or something else?
I want to have (something like) a glossary with "3 columns" ie. not just word and meaning, but word, single letter shortform, and meaning.
The usage I want is that in the running text I would like to have the word linked to the glossary or at least highlighted some way.  And in the margin, right aligned I indicate the short code that is referenced.
Also at the paper I want a short table of code : word.
At the end of the paper I want a detailed table of all three.
Is glossaries what I should be looking at? Or acronym or something else?
Also any example pointers would help.
